# New Team Foundation Server 2013 can not find database?

Tags: tfs

We have installed a new installation of TFS2013.  When we start the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, we get an error message...

```
TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database.
Verify that the server taht is hosting the database is operational, and
that the network problems are not blocking communication with the server.
```

This error makes little sense, as the database server and TFS server are both on the same machine, so network issues can' be the problem.  I'm pretty sure that the error message is incorrect.

I was hoping to find a place that I could check the connection string of the server and db that TFS is trying to use, but that doesn't seem possible.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.  All info I can find when I search that error code don't seem to apply in my case.

Comment: is the DB service running? can you connect to it?

Comment: Network admin set up the original TFS instance.  He decided to drop the virtual server and restore it fresh without TFS.  I'll see how a second install works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection string is stored in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config` and some other places.

`<appSettings>
  <add key="applicationDatabase" value="Data Source=MYMACHINE\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Tfs_Configuration;Integrated Security=True" />
  <!-- ... -->
</appSettings>`

You can use `TfsConfig remapDBs` to force the correct connection string.